# Algorithm for operating on 2d array with radius

Tags: java

trying to think of the best way to handle this problem with my 2d game. I want to be able to specify a coordinate pair (x,y) and a radius value. Given this information, I want to operate on all elements of the gameMap[][].

So if radius = 0:

```
X
```

if radius = 1:

```
xxx
xxx
xxx
```

if radius = 2:

```
xxxxx
xxxxx
xxxxx
xxxxx
xxxxx
```

This is what I have so far, which falls apart if radius > 1

```
for(int i = 1; i < radius; i++) {
                // right
                setAreaObject(locX+i, locY+i);
                setAreaObject(locX+i, (locY+i)-1);
                setAreaObject(locX+i, locY-i);

                // center
                setAreaObject((locX+i)-1, locY+i);
                setAreaObject((locX+i)-1, (locY+i)-1);
                setAreaObject((locX+i)-1, locY-i);

                // left
                setAreaObject(locX-i, locY+i);
                setAreaObject(locX-i, (locY+i)-1);
                setAreaObject(locX-i, locY-i);
            }
```

Thanks for any thoughts or ideas

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
for(int x = locX - radius; x <= locX + radius; x++)
{
    for(int y = locY - radius; y <= locY + radius; y++)
    {
            setAreaObject(x, y);
    }
}
```

If you want the radius to act in two dimensions, you need to loop in two dimensions. Your code loops in only one, and then manually handles the +/- 1 in the Y direction, which is why it doesn't scale. Walk through the loop manually, one iteration at a time, and write down the calls to setAreaObject manually to better understand the way the loop is being evaluated.

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
for (int x = locX - radius; x <= locX + radius; ++x) {
    for (int y = locY - radius; y <= locY + radius; ++y) {
        setAreaObject(x, y);
    }
}
```

We have a nested loop to iterate `radius` times over both dimensions. Basically, you can think of the problem as calling `setAreaObject` on a square that is `radius` by `radius` size. Thinking about it this way, you can see that we can do this by iterating over every y-coordinate of every x-coordinate in that square, for a total of `radius` * `radius` iterations.